# Cannot open Java project in WSL2 with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsl-2

Warning: I solved this problem already. I want to provide the documentation in case someone faces it. When I try to open java project IntelliJ won't open it. However, it could easily non-Java project. Logs:

```
Exit code: 0
2023-04-07 18:53:38,277 [ 207458]   INFO - #c.j.g.s.d.m.HostRunMethods - Host status: UnattendedHostStatus(appPid=22067, appVersion=IU-231.8109.144, runtimeVersion=17.0.6b829.5, unattendedMode=true, backendUnresponsive=false, modalDialogIsOpened=false, idePath=/home/mdmytren/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/9873067aa121a_ideaIU-231.8109.144, projects=null)
2023-04-07 18:53:39,288 [ 208469] SEVERE - #c.j.g.s.d.m.HostRunMethods - Remote IDE backend failed to open a project
java.lang.Throwable: Remote IDE backend failed to open a project
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:202)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods.openProject(HostRunMethods.kt:203)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods.access$openProject(HostRunMethods.kt:30)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods$openProject$1.invokeSuspend(HostRunMethods.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1$3.invokeSuspend(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:172)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:158)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$createModal$1$1.run(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressSynchronously$9(CoreProgressManager.java:513)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-04-07 18:53:39,292 [ 208473] SEVERE - #c.j.g.s.d.m.HostRunMethods - JetBrains Gateway 2022.3.2  Build #GW-223.8617.56
2023-04-07 18:53:39,292 [ 208473] SEVERE - #c.j.g.s.d.m.HostRunMethods - JDK: 17.0.5; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-04-07 18:53:39,296 [ 208477] SEVERE - #c.j.g.s.d.m.HostRunMethods - OS: Windows 11
2023-04-07 18:53:40,333 [ 209514]   INFO - #c.j.g.s.d.DeployErrorProcessor - Deploy failed with exception, will show deploy failure UI
com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: Host did not provide good status in 60 seconds
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.DeployFlowUtil$fullDeployCycleImpl$2.invokeSuspend(DeployFlowUtil.kt:197)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1$3.invokeSuspend(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:172)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$create$task$1.invoke(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:158)
    at com.intellij.openapi.rd.util.CoroutineProgressContext$Companion$createModal$1$1.run(BackgroundProgressCoroutineUtil.kt:203)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressSynchronously$9(CoreProgressManager.java:513)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$new$0(ProgressRunner.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: Host did not provide good status in 60 seconds
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.DeployFlowUtil$fullDeployCycleImpl$2.invokeSuspend(DeployFlowUtil.kt:192)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.DeployException: Host did not provide good status in 60 seconds
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods.openProject(HostRunMethods.kt:211)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods.access$openProject(HostRunMethods.kt:30)
    at com.jetbrains.gateway.ssh.deploy.methods.HostRunMethods$openProject$1.invokeSuspend(HostRunMethods.kt)
    ... 35 more
2023-04-07 18:53:40,346 [ 209527]   INFO - #c.j.g.w.e.WslHostCommandExecutor - Starting a WSL process: /bin/bash, -lc, echo REMOTE_EXEC_OUTPUT_MARKER_ && /home/mdmytren/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/remote-dev-worker/remote-dev-worker_ba9509c11d96c6ce33a39e248d584be92d7de751a8acb9b7e9872b6136aa4876 product-code --ide-path=/home/mdmytren/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/9873067aa121a_ideaIU-231.8109.144
```

I checked my IntelliJ configurations and they look in the following way:
[image]

My solution will be in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was using SDK from Windows, not from the WSL2[image]

[image]